# var_dump a variable return nothing in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have some variable and try to echoing them but I see empty result (test on live server). I cannot find my mistake, please help..

My controller:

```
function request($req)
{
    $tiki_url = "http://203.77.231.130/services/api.cfc?method=tariff&origin=CGK01.00&destination={TO_AREA}&weight=1";
    var_dump($tiki_url);

    $code = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('request_id = ', $req );
    $query = $this->db->get('excel');
    $sql= $query->result_array(); 
    var_dump($sql);

    foreach ($sql as $key) 
    {
        $ex =$key['excel_id'];
        $zipcode = $key['to_zipcode'];
        $request = $key['request_id'];
        $this->db->select('tariff_code');
        $this->db->where('zip_code = ', $zipcode );
        $query = $this->db->get('area_info'); 
        $tarif= $query->row_array();
        $kodepos = $tarif['tariff_code'] ;
        var_dump($kodepos);

        if(isset($code[$kodepos]))
        {
            $tiki_data = $code[$kodepos];
        } 
        else
        {
            $url = str_replace("{TO_AREA}",$kodepos,$tiki_url);
            $tiki_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),TRUE);
            $code[$kodepos] = $tiki_data ;
        }

        $tariff = $tiki_data['tariff'][3]['TARIFF'] ;
        var_dump($tariff);

        $data = array(
                'tariff'=>$tariff,
                );
        var_dump($data);

        $data_status = array(
            'status' => '2',
            );
        var_dump($data_status);

        $this->db->update('excel', $data, "excel_id =".$ex);
        $this->db->update('request',$data_status, "request_id=".$request);

        var_dump($key);

        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE, "total" => $tariff,"excel" => $ex ));
    }
}
```

All var_dump() returns nothing except the `var_dump($tiki_url)`. I am sure there are several records in `excel` table. I expected this result from echoing the json_encode (I capture this from testing on localhost):

[image]

Comment: `$sql` is empty? What is `$query`? And what is `$this->db`?

Answer (score 2):

Only the first one returns the data, so we can guess that there was an error with SQL queries. You can check using the [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function.

```
...
$sql = $query->result_array();
if ( ! is_array($sql)) {
    exit('Error.');
}
var_dump($sql);
...
```

Comment: i added is_array() as you suggest me, but it gives me nothing :(

Comment: sorry, it gives me `array(0){}` @Juno_okyo

Comment: @MaiMunah I just take a look at the CI's user guide. You can try to make some changes:

From: $this->db->where('request_id = ', $req);
To: $this->db->where('request_id', $req);

From: $this->db->where('zip_code = ', $zipcode );
To: $this->db->where('zip_code', $zipcode );

Comment: I changed it as your suggestion but still not working. btw, about the `where` syntax, I use the `->where('request_id=',$req)` in other controller but it works fine.